# position input above div containing custom googlemaps

Tags: html, css, input, positioning

I have made a custom google maps with a custom input field.

My problem is I can't set the "searchBox" container above my google maps container.

I have tried different properties, e.g.

- position: absolute
- position: relative
- z-index
- top

when i load the page now the "wagmp_map_3" layer overlays "searchBox" 
of course this should be the other way arround

Here is my code below

**CSS**

```
#formContainter{ position: absolute ;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="formContainter">
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <input type="text" name="searchBox" id="searchBox" />
      <input type="submit" name="SearchBtn" id="SearchBtn" value="Zoek" />
    </form>
</div>
<div id="wagmp_map_3" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
```

I have searched for similar questions here on stackoverflow but could only find 'Positioning div elements above input elements' or other relative subjects not leading to a solution.

Comment: can you create a fiddle please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/of9vs4jt/ -- here is a JSFIDDLE my googlemaps contains a js file i cant get jsfiddle to work, it would be without maps

Comment: Is there any way of forcing position Absolute? Maybe with Javascript...

Comment: the fiddle looks fine for me, both in FF and Chrome, not sure what your question is

Comment: I made a new test file with this html script from here -- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox?hl=nl -- and i dont understand why the searchbox is working there?!?!

Comment: again, your fiddle is working

Comment: when i add the JS file (for maps) it floats above my Input field :(

Comment: I think that i finally found a solution... adding { left: 31px; top: 35px; z-index:999; }  did the trick, but it might be an issue for later with adding responsive design